# What's the proper way to set up a WCF service with a EF database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, wcf

I'm working on a project to become more familiar with WCF services and Entity Framework and I ran into a road block. I currently have a simple WCF service with an EF code first database context implemented in a separate class library. I also have a console application to host the service and a client to use the service. This leaves me with the following 2 questions:

1. Given that I'm using 'code first to a new database', where is the proper place to initialize the database? Would the service itself handle this or should it be initialized within the service host? My idea was to create/initialize the database within the host and treat it as an existing database within the service.
2. A regular user client should only have read access to the database; however, I'll need something along the lines of an 'admin' client that has the ability to add/remove entries. What is the correct way to have multiple clients access the database through a single service, but provide them with different permissions?

I've taken a look at the following two articles - [this one](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/create-a-simple-wcf-service-against-pubs-database-using-ef-linq-part-i/) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127395/Implementing-a-WCF-Service-with-Entity-Framework). However, these both discuss using an existing database and didn't really answer my questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1) The service host should not know about your DB platform as in the next day you can host your as service as windows service for example and don't want do copy code between hosts,so it's better to initalize in the service (by using a separated DAL)

2) Mange your application privileges and pass those access token from each client, You can base your code to sync with AD,Self-development ot any other method you will like

Comment: So to make sure I understand correctly, the access hierarchy should look something like this: 
Client -> Service -> DAL -> Database
Where the database is initialized within the service itself, not the service host.

And in the second case, I understand what you mean but am not sure how to do this. I'm guessing it involves multiple service contracts. I will research it for now.